# Open a local pdf file with cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

Im using cordova 3.3.0 and i would like to open a local pdf file and then close it on user demand.

```
ref = window.open(encodeURI(path), '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('exit', function() {
    ref.removeEventListener('exit', function(){});
    ref.close();
```

} );

This opens a file in inapp browser but i cannot get back to the actual app when I open some pdf file. How to add some close button or something ?

Im trying to get this working on ios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long time since you asked this but just had exactly the same issue.  I had to install the inAppBrowser plugin on my project and the Done button appeared.  Without the plugin installed, the pdf opened but the Done button was not shown.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to answer my question :)

Comment: @dinodsaurus what is the path format? I have the PDF files under the www folder but I can't get any path to work, could any of you guys give an example?

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work.  On iOS a "Done" button should appear in the lower left of the screen.

[image]

```
function openPDF(){
            ref = window.open('http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
            ref.addEventListener('exit', function() {
                ref.removeEventListener('exit', function(){});
                ref.close();
            } );
        }
```

I tested on iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.  Of course you can set location=no to remove the URL at the bottom.

Comment: This doesn't work on Android for viewing PDFs. The page remains blank.

Comment: and this doesn't even answer the question. the example provided is an external file. the OP's question is about the local files.